# Problems importing files with read.csv

Tags: r

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE, sep=" ", dec=" ")
```

actual output:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: Please paste your data as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you intend for comma to be the separator on each line.  So, try the following:

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE, strip.white=TRUE, sep=",", dec=" ")
```

Actually, comma is the default separator used by `read.csv`, so you can probably simplify your call to this:

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE, fill=TRUE, strip.white=TRUE, dec=" ")
```